# How would I get the colour of a pixel within a program using the windows library in cpp?

Tags: c++, windows

I know how to get the colour of a certain pixel on the screen via:

```
HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, x, y);
```

However, `GetDC` retrieves the whole screen if the parameter is NULL. How would I get it to retrieve the colour of a specific pixel for a program, say for Notepad instead of the whole screen?

Please note I'm pretty new to C++ so it would be good if you explained it in layman's terms.

Comment: [`GetDC()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc) wants the window handle (`HWND`) of that program (or any of it's child windows) to restirct the area you retrieve.

Comment: How would I find the window handle of say notepad.exe?

Comment: @orang3juic3 look at `FindWindow()` or `EnumWindows()`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! How would I simulate a left click to those x,y coords. I googled how to simulate a left click and it works, however the coords  used to simulate a left click are in the context of the whole screen, not the window. How would I get the coords of a point in my program and left click on them? I imagine it's something like finding the 0,0 coord of the program in the context of the screen.

Comment: This reads like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you *really* trying to accomplish?